# How do I change Windows 10 fonts?

Tags: fonts, windows-10, cleartype

With Windows 7 it was possible to change the fonts used by Windows for title bar, menus, popups, etc.

This way I could get rid of "anti-aliased" fonts such as Segoe UI that are blurry and use "aliased" fonts such as Tahoma that are sharper and much more readable for me. That, and disabling ClearType give me the right fonts display configuration.

I cannot find this fonts configuration dialog in Windows 10 so far.

Where can I find this dialog for Windows 10? (*sorry about the French snapshot*)

[image: Windows 7 fonts configuration dialog]

Comment: this dialog was removed in Windows 8. try if this tool allows it: http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.1836

Answer (score 4):

This dialog does not exist anymore as it seems.

Instead to change the font, I executed this reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]

"Segoe UI (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]

"Segoe UI"="Tahoma"
```